# Parsing the tags to get the list of contains

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm working on my PHP to generating the xml output. I use simple_html_dom method to parsing the contains from my script called get-listing.php.

Here is my PHP script called myscript.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$link;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$base1 = "http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php";
$html = file_get_html($base1);   

$countp = $html->find('p');     
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$xml .= "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
//echo $xml;
$xml .= '<tv generator-info-name="www.testbox.elementfx.com/xmltv">';
?>
```

Output for get-listing.php:

```
<p id='channels'>ABC FAMILY</p><p id='links'><a href='http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=ABC FAMILY&id=101'></p><a id="aTest" href="">Stream 1</a><br><br><p id='channels'>102 CBS</p><p id='links'><a href='http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=CBS&id=102'></p><a id="aTest" href="">Stream 1</a><br><br>
```

Here is the output for ABC-FAMILY:

```
<span id="time1">9:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">17 Again</span><br><br><span id="time2">11:00 PM </span> - <span id="title2">The 700 Club</span><br><br>
```

Here is the output for CBS:

```
<span id="time1">9:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">Unforgettable: Til Death</span><br><br><span id="time2">10:00 PM </span> - <span id="title2">Hawaii Five-0: Ho'i Hou</span><br><br>
```

I'm creating the variable so I can connect to get-listing.php script. I want to create the loops variable to get the list of url from get-listing.php with each html tag called `<p id="links">`. And also I want to get the list of contains from the get-listing.php when I open on each url. The contains I want to get from the tags is called `<span id="title1">` and `<span id="title2">`.

Can you please tell me how I can create the loops to get the list of url from each tag `<p id='links'>` to open them using with `simple_html_dom` and how I can get the list of contains I want to get?

Comment: does anyone know how???

Comment: There should only be one element with id="links". Also, it's hard to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @pguardiario yes, there are one element with id="links". What I want to do is to create the loops variable to allow me to get every element with id="links" with list of arrays. And when I get the list of arrays, I want to connect on each url for each array to get the elements called `<span id="title1">` and `<span id="title2">`. Can you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: You say there is only one but that you need to get *every* one. Do you see the problem?

Comment: yes I can get every element with id="links", but i need to know how i can send request to each url to get each response with list of elements. how i can do that?

Comment: @pguardiario do you know how?